# Recursion between different objects and combine them uniquely, without duplicate

Tags: javascript, recursion, es5-shim

I've been trying to figure out how to do recursion for 2 objects that have similar properties, but also have differences. I need to merge these 2 objects in a unique way, so there are no duplicate countries or models etc.

**EDIT**: in vanilla js only please

```js
var us1 = {
  country: {
    "United States": {
      "Ford": {
        "engine": {
          type1: "4 cyl",
          type2: "6 cyl"
        }
      },
      "Chevy": {
        "engine": {
          type1: "6 cyl"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var us2 = {
  country: {
    "United States": {
      "Ford": {
        "engine": {
          type3: "12 cyl"
        }
      },
      "Saturn": {
        "engine": {
          type1: "4 cyl"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var cars = [us1, us2];
var newCars = [];

function fn(cars) {
  if (typeof cars == "object") {
    for (var attr in cars) {
      if (!newCars.hasOwnProperty(cars[attr])) {
        newCars.push(cars[attr]);
      }

      fn(cars[attr])
    }
  } else {
    //
  }
}

console.log(fn(cars));
console.log(newCars)
```

**Result wanted:** 

    `var us1 = {
      country: {
        "United States": {
          "Ford": {
            "engine": {
              type1: "4 cyl",
              type2: "6 cyl",
              type2: "12 cyl"
            }
          },
          "Chevy": {
            "engine": {
              type1: "6 cyl"
            }
          },
          "Saturn": {
            "engine": {
              type1: "4 cyl"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }`

Comment: I was thinking get every property and keep iterating til its over

Comment: Do you have to use recursion?

Comment: No I dont, I guess I thought it was the only concept to this problem

Comment: Can you show your result in actual Javascript or JSON form so we know exactly what you want?

Comment: Check out this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/383245/5651

Comment: @jfriend00 added actual result wanted

Comment: @jessegavin I think it is what i'm looking for, ill test it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a library, it's trivial to write yourself. Something along the lines of

```
// (to: Object, ...sources: Object[]) => Object
function mergeDeep(to) {
  const sources = Array.from(arguments).slice(1)

  // (to: Object, from: Object) => void
  const _merge = (to, from) => {
    for (let a in from) {
      if (a in to) {
        _merge(to[a], from[a])
      } else {
        to[a] = from[a]
      }
    }
  }

  sources.forEach(from => {
    _merge(to, from)
  })

  return to
}
```

See demo here https://tonicdev.com/bcherny/mergedeep

But really, you should be using a library for this. Writing it yourself is guaranteed to be buggier and slower than any widely used existing implementation.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not sure we're looking at the same code.. OP doesn't seem to have `4 6 cyl` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs):

```
_.merge(us1, us2)
```

Comment: is there a way to do it only in vanilla JS?

Comment: technically this works in lodash, but i dont want to add lodash just for this functionality, ill still +1 for working answer

Comment: @jfriend00 it was fault on my behalf I comma separated them, I also updated the question right away. Sorry about that, didnt mean to confuse you guys. I still need that obj to be deep merged together, but only in vanilla js. I appreciate you looking into this issue, hoping I can still get an answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you are open to use underscore.js, the following should work:

```
_.extend(us1, us2)
```

Comment: Does this really turn individual properties into an array to merge their contents?  Somehow I doubt it.

Comment: `_.extend` does a shallow merge - OP is asking for a deep merge.

Comment: Wasn't aware the OP is asking for a deep merge specifically.  The above answer gives what OP wanted literally.